# Pythonic way of writing multiple regex tests

Tags: python

How to write in a Pythonic way when there are multiple regex patterns to test with and extract matched groups if a test succeeds?

That is to say, what is the Pythonic equivalent of the following code snippet?

```
if re.match(pattern1, string):
    m = re.match(pattern1, string)
    grps = m.groups()
    ...[process matched groups for pattern1]...
elif re.match(pattern2, string):
    m = re.match(pattern2, string)
    grps = m.groups()
    ...[process matched groups for pattern2]...
elif re.match(pattern3, string):
    m = re.match(pattern3, string)
    grps = m.groups()
    ...[process matched groups for pattern3]...
```

Comment: How complicated are these regex patterns? You _could_ combine them into  single regex. Or it may be easier to just put them into a list (or tuple) and loop over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I want is:

```
m = re.match(pattern1, string)
if m:
    grps = m.groups()
    print(pattern1)
else:
    m = re.match(pattern2, string)
    if m:
        grps = m.groups()
        print(pattern2)
```

And this is the best style I have found, which mimics a `case` statement existing in many languages:

```
while True:
    m = re.match(pattern1, string)
    if m:
        grps = m.groups()
        print(pattern1)
        break
    m = re.match(pattern2, string)
    if m:
        grps = m.groups()
        print(pattern2)
        break
```

Not sure I'm the inventor of `case` in Python. But from the text we can see the second one has constant indentation, while the first one has linear indentation. The algorithm professor has told us `O(1)` is better than `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
patterns = [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3]
for pattern in patterns:
    m = re.match(pattern, string)
    if m:
        grps = m.groups()
        ...
        break
```

Comment: Different patterns need to be processed differently. So there will be additional if...else... nested deeper in the statement. Not sure if this is Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function for each pattern that handles the resulting groups. Then you can use list comprehension:

```
lst = [(pattern1, func1), (p2, f2)...]
results = [func(match.groups()) for (match, func) in [(re.match(patt, theStr), func) for (patt, func) in lst] if match]
```